# using a if statement inside a while loop

Tags: php

I have a while loop that returns X amount of data with the same value X amount of times before it changes to a different value.

```
// example 121, 121, 121, 121, 113, 113, 113, 113
```

each value is on its own line so a while loops puts them on the next 
is it possible to have an if that uses  when the value changes ?

some thing like

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if ($row["name"] == $row["name"]){
         echo "<tr><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["combi"]."</td>"
    }else{
         echo "<td>".$row["combi"]."</td></tr>"
    }
}
```

Comment: `$row["name"] == $row["name"]` - this will always be true, I suppose. You can use a temporary variable to store previous name, but I wonder can't you do the same thing with `GROUP BY`-ing your query instead.

Comment: Simply make a `group by name` clause within your query

Answer (score 1):

You just use another variable to stock the last value

```
<?php
$lastval = 0;
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    if ($row["name"] != $lastval){
        $lastval = $row["name"];
        // value has changed
    }else{
        // Value is the same as the last one
    }
}
?>
```

Don't forget to "ORDER BY name"